# Dealing with data in Docker Containers with Gitlab-Ci

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

So I am using gitlab-ci to deploy my websites in docker containers, because the gitlab-ci docker runner doesn't seem to do what I want to do I am using the shell executor and let it run `docker-compose up -d`. Here comes the problem.

I have 2 volumes in my docker-container. `./:/var/www/html/` (which is the content of my git repo, so files I want to replace on build) and a mount that is "inside" of this mount `/srv/data:/var/www/html/software/permdata` (which is a persistent mount on my server).

When the gitlab-ci runner starts it tries to remove all files while the container is running, but because of this mount in mount it gets a `device busy` and aborts. So I have to manually stop and remove the container before I can run my build (which kind of defeats the point of build automation).

Options I thought about to fix this problem:

1. stop and remove the container before gitlab-ci-multi-runner starts (seems not possible)
2. add the git data to my docker container and only mount my permdata (seems like you can't add data to a container without the volume option with docker compose like you can in a Dockerfile)

Option 2 would be ideal because then it would also sort out my issues with permissions on the files.
Maybe someone has gone through the same problem and could give me an advice

Answer (score 0):

> seems like you can't add data to a container without the volume option with docker compose like you can in a Dockerfile

That's correct. The Compose file is not meant to replace the Dockerfile, it's meant to run multiple images for an application or project.

You can modify the `Dockerfile` to copy in the git files.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that. But creating a new Dockerfile and image for every Container is not desirable for this issue as it would create a huge list of new issues.